# What does -webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2 stand for?

Tags: iphone, css, media

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width:480px), 
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
{ /*iphone css*/ }
```

*max-device width* makes sense but *pixel ratio* doesn't make any sense to me. thanks.

Comment: This is mainly used to identify newer mac retina displays with high resolution. These screens use built in zooming that can cause css to not work as intended.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

From http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

> The -webkit-device-pixel-ratio CSS media query. Use this to specify
>   the screen densities for which this style sheet is to be used. The
>   corresponding value should be either "0.75", "1", or "1.5", to
>   indicate that the styles are for devices with low density, medium
>   density, or high density screens, respectively. For example:   The hdpi.css stylesheet is only used for devices
>   with a screen pixel ration of 1.5, which is the high density pixel
>   ratio.

And according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Media_queries

> -moz-device-pixel-ratio
>
> Gives the number of device pixels per CSS pixel.
>
> Note: This media feature is also implemented by Webkit as
>   -webkit-device-pixel-ratio. The min and max prefixes as implemented by Gecko are named min--moz-device-pixel-ratio and
>   max--moz-device-pixel-ratio; but the same prefixes as implemented by
>   Webkit are named -webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio and
>   -webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. I read elsewhere on SO about using `(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0)` as a hack for browser-conditional CSS. Now with `(min--moz-device-pixel-ratio:0)` a stylesheet can detect Gecko/Mozilla browsers. Does something similar hold for other browsers?

Comment: "i think w3c doesn't support this". Isn't the lack of w3c standard for that why there are vendor specific prefixes (-webkit or -moz, though not quite a prefix there)?

Comment: This is a good query to catch 'em (the hight dpi devices) nearly all:
https://gist.github.com/marcedwards/3446599