# What are typical device pixel ratios?

Tags: html, mobile-website

As a web developer, what device pixel ratios should I design for? I've only come across 1.5 and 2.0, should I be aware of any others?

Comment: Take a look - http://stackoverflow.com/a/9437635/981134

Answer (score 1):

Generally 1.5 and 2.0 are going to cover your bases.  There aren't any devices that come to mind that can utilize anything more than a "2" pixel ratio, and devices that can't display a perfect "2" will still display better than a low res image.